# Use Asus M4A88T-M internal graphics with PCIe-graphics

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce, integrated-graphics

I have an Asus M4A88T-M Motherboard with an internal ATI HD4250 graphics card. I also have a Nvidia Geforce GFX460 sitting on my PCIe-Port.
I want to use 3 Screens and for this, I want to use the internal HDMI or VGA-Port, but it doesn't appear in my Screensettings in Windows 7 Enterprise. The internal graphics card also doesn't appear in my device-manager.

How do I re-enable my internal graphics? I know that my motherboard is able to use ATI Surround-View...

Comment: You're mixing ATI and nVidia cards. This has been known to work in some instances, but it takes a lot of work to get the drivers all set up and is generally a **Bad Idea(TM)** as windows doesn't like having multiple graphics drivers loaded.

Comment: Hi again, I installed Linux mint alongside Windows 7. You said, it's a bad idea to run multiple graphics cards from different vendors under Windows 7 but what about Linux? Is there any chance to get this to work?

Comment: Pretty much an even more crazier idea. Things might be A BIT better if you (and your card) can deal with using only the in-kernel FOSS drivers (for nvidia cards it's the RE driver `nouveau`). Nevertheless, X will not make things easier for you to use multiple cards.